# Why does the div go past the image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a header over an image and the length is going past the image if that makes sense. Why is this? Here is a snippet

[image]

```html
<table border="0" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="background-color: #002c5f; padding: 5px;"><span style="color: white;">TEST</span></div>
        <div style="padding: auto; display: block;">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://cdn-ds.com/media/websites/3637/content/1920x1080_AA5_D_161026.jpg?s=530799" alt="" width="350" height="250" /></div>
      </td>
      <td><img class="img-responsive" src="https://cdn-ds.com/media/websites/3637/content/1920x1080_AA5_161008.jpg?s=700334" alt="" width="350" height="250" /></td>
      <td><img class="img-responsive" src="https://cdn-ds.com/media/websites/3637/content/1920x1080_Virtual-Cockpit.jpg?s=245934" alt="" width="350" height="250" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code you provided, it looks fine on my side (tested on FF and Chrome). On which browser are you working ?

Comment: I can reproduce this by adding css such as `img {margin-right:1px;}`, but that would be cheating, wouldn't it.

Comment: I can see the image but similarly cannot reproduce the effect.  I suspect it might be some inherited css having an impact...  A "quiick fix" might be to base it on the implied fix above img {margin-right:-1px;}
You might also Consider trying a css reset to see if there is any effect?
https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
Lastly, for validation and for maintainability, I'd suggest removing the invalid html formatting for the table elements, and move the inline styling into a class perhaps?